# How the hashCode() and equals() overriding actually works?

Tags: equals, hashcode, overriding

I just read from a book and it said that as long as we override an `equals()` method from the Object class, its `hashCode()` method should be overriden also, but I do not really understand why we have to override the `hashCode()` method also. Let's consider a following example below:

```
public class Employee {
    public int employeeId;
    public String firstName, lastName;
    public int yearStarted;

    Employee(){}

    Employee(int employeeID){
        this.employeeId = employeeID;
    }

//  @Override
//  public int hashCode() {
//      return employeeId;
//  }

    public boolean equals(Object e) {
         if(!(e instanceof Employee)){
             return false;
         }
         else {
             Employee newEmp = (Employee)e;
             return this.employeeId == newEmp.employeeId;
         }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee one = new Employee(101);
        if (one.equals(new Employee(101)))
            System.out.println("Success");
        else
            System.out.println("Failure");
    }
}
```

And when running I get "**Success**" result, while I override only an `equals()`, but not `hashCode()`. So what does the process flow that related to the `hashCode()` when overriding the `equals()` method actually look like and in which case do we need to override both `hashCode()` and `equals()`? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is rather a convention to override both `equals()` and `hashCode()`. The reason for that is that many library utilities, such as `HashMap` rely on the consistency of both methods. In fact, for two objects `a` and `b`, if `a.equals(b)` is `true`, then also `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()` should be `true`.

You might want to read about hash-based data structures to understand this requirement in more detail, e.g., here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table